# getting the error "The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing. "

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

I'm trying to create a lms with django. So I have a separate model for the teachers who can upload the courses, and another model for courses. The code is below:
models.py

```
class teacher(models.Model):
    name=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    area=models.ManyToManyField(subject)
    description=RichTextField()


class course(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    areas=models.ManyToManyField(subject)
    description=RichTextField()
    instructor=models.ForeignKey(teacher, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    material=models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In my views.py file:

```
instr=teacher.objects.filter(name=request.user)
data2=models.course.objects.filter(instructor__name__username=instr)
    
return render(request, "course/profile.html", {'datas':a, 'courses': data, 'creations':data2})
```

in the templete:

```
<div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Created Courses</label>
                {% for data in creations %}
                <form action="/course/" method="GET">
                    <div class="w3-display-container w3-col s12 m4 l4 w3-section">
                      <div class="card" style="width: 30rem; height: 30rem;">
                        <div class="card-body hover_trans_grey">
                          <h5 class="card-title">{{data.title}}</h5>
                          <h6 class='card-title'>Uploaded by {{data.instructor.name}}</h6>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w3-button" name="s" value="{{data.pk}}">Go to Course</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      
                       
                      </div>
                    
                    
                  </form>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

I get the error:
[image]

What is the way to remove this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instr` is a `QuerySet` you can't add it to the filter directly like you did.
You can get list of courses directly by using `request.user`

```
data2=models.course.objects.filter(instructor__name=request.user)
return render(request, "course/profile.html", {'datas':a, 'courses': data, 'creations':data2})
```

if you want to get the `teacher` first then you have to use `get`:

```
instr=teacher.objects.get(name=request.user)   
data2=models.course.objects.filter(instructor=instr)

return render(request, "course/profile.html", {'datas':a, 'courses': data, 'creations':data2})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put [__in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) after `instructor` because `instr` is **a queryset** made by [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#filter) as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

instr=teacher.objects.filter(name=request.user)
data2=models.course.objects.filter(instructor__in=instr) # Here
# data2=models.course.objects.filter(instructor__name__username=instr)
```

And, if you use [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get), you don't need to put `__in` after `instructor` because `instr` is an object as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"
                     # ↓ Here
instr=teacher.objects.get(name=request.user)
# instr=teacher.objects.filter(name=request.user)
data2=models.course.objects.filter(instructor__in=instr) # Here
# data2=models.course.objects.filter(instructor__name__username=instr)
```